# How to query an array list in a Firebase document?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to query my database for an android application, if a username is in the 'fave' array field of my database and if so then change the background of an image. My database is set up like this...

[image: WHERE THE FIELD IS IN MY DATABASE]

I don't know if i'm doing it right but currently i think i may be checking the whole collection rather than a specific document and it's not even returning anything. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: I suggest starting with the documentation to learn how to do queries.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Comment: @DougStevenson sorry maybe i should have been more clear. In the documentation the query objects search a whole collection but i only want to search a specific document, as the user can be in multiple trainers 'fave' arrays

Comment: Then just get() the document you're looking for. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Comment: @DougStevenson if i add the .document() path afterwards i can no longer use the .whereInArray()_

Comment: Yes, you can't filter when identifying a specific document.  There's no need to - you already know the document ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wanted this?

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Trainers").document("Air Force 1 Low").get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
        List<String> list = (List<String>)documentSnapshot.get("fave");
        for (String name : list){
            if (name.equals("Admin")){
                //do if user is admin
                return;
            }
        }
        //do if user is not admin
    }
});
```

Comment: Top lad. I've been struggling to get my head round how to query documents but this has helped a lot. Thanks!